# LibGDX SelectBox. Ничего не выделяется

Tags: libgdx

Пытаюсь использовать SelectBox в libgdx. Бокс создаётся, нажимаю на него - открывается список элементов. Только вот выбрать какой-то элемент невозможно. Сколько ни щёлкай по ним.

Вот мой код:

```
    final SelectBox<String> language = new SelectBox<String>(mSkin);
    final Array<String> langs = new Array<String>();
    langs.add(bundle.get("english"));
    langs.add(bundle.get("russian"));
    language.setItems(langs);
    language.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            // Этот код никогда не вызывается!
            Log.message(getClass(), "select: " + language.getSelected());
        }
    });
                                           ...
table.add(language);
                                           ...
table.setFillParent(true);

    table.pack();

    mStage.addActor(table);
```

В [этом](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/UITest.java) примере использование select box'а точно такое же. Где ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забыл в render() вызвать act(). Всё заработало.